# Accessing the head from anywhere STL list

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

In order to get the next element in the list one just needs to increase the iterator.  However from any element in the list, is there a way to get directly to the head of a list?  For example if iterator is pointing to the third element of a list, is there a way to get to the front of the list besides iterating backwards ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because `std::list` is designed to model a doubly-linked list (and is usually implemented as one), and in a doubly linked list, each element only has pointers to the previous and next element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

No, and you cannot even do it just based on having one single iterator: You have no way of knowing whether the iterator is valid, and whether you are allowed to increment or decrement it!

The only way you could do it would be by comparing your iterator (presumed valid) to `x.begin()` and `x.end()`, but once you have those, you already have the iterator to the list head and the question becomes moot.

Iterators should always be thought of as coming in pairs `[first, last)`, and containers provide such a pair with their `begin()/end()` member functions.